# Default value for GPS

Tags: android, gps

I have an android app based on location. My question is : Can I have default value for GPS , for example, if I am in X city and I want to show a message for user : you are not in Y city (Which is a default city). 
Is that possible !

Comment: You can resolve the GPS to a city name using Google. and check that for inequality.

Comment: Actually, I don't use Google map.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reverse Geo-Coding functionality in Google MAPS API on latitude and longitude information with you.

Comment: I don't use Google map.

Comment: If you know City Y coordinates, you can probably just compare X with Y and notify user.

Comment: OK but if the user inside city Y. if I compare it so it will show you are not in city Y. Actually, I  think I could use Geo Fence but I don't know if it is work.